# JQuery nextUntil traversal in table

Tags: jquery, html

I got this calender table where i need to hightlight the range from the pickup date maby 10 Feb. to set date 20 Feb

```
<tr class="rd-days-row">
    <td class="rd-day-body rd-day-disabled">09</td>
    <td class="rd-day-body">10</td>
    <td class="rd-day-body">11</td>
    <td class="rd-day-body">12</td>
    <td class="rd-day-body">13</td>
    <td class="rd-day-body">14</td>
    <td class="rd-day-body">15</td>
</tr>

<tr class="rd-days-row">
    <td class="rd-day-body">16</td>
    <td class="rd-day-body">17</td>
    <td class="rd-day-body">18</td>
    <td class="rd-day-body">19</td>
    <td class="rd-day-body rd-day-selected">20</td>
    <td class="rd-day-body">21</td>
    <td class="rd-day-body">22</td>
</tr>
```

So i need to find the td with the class rd-day-disabled and go from the select elm to rd-day-selected and add a css style for all between i have try some thing like

```
$(".rd-container-attachment-two .rd-day-body.rd-day-disabled").last().nextUntil(".rd-day-body.rd-day-selected")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".rd-container-attachment-two .rd-day-body.rd-day-disabled").last().nextUntil(".rd-day-body.rd-day-selected")
```

You missed a `.` in `nextUntil()`

Comment: But that not the issue just me typing to fast :)
nextUntil() stop traversing when i meet an tr ind the array